# PHP imagecopyresampled() without height

Tags: php, upload

I have this piece of code here

```
imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,$x,$y,$thumb_width,$thumb_width,$width,$height);
```

Baiscally what I am trying to do is upload an image and resize the width and have the height adjusted based on the width.

I tried this also

```
imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,$x,$y,$thumb_width,$thumb_width,$width);
```

without the height and got this error

```
Warning: Wrong parameter count for imagecopyresampled() in /home/content/44/8713044/html/admin/Categories.php on line 63
```

this is the current code where the `$width` and `$height` variables come from.

```
if($width> $height) {
            $x = ceil(($width - $height) / 2 );
            $width = $height;
        } elseif($height> $width) {
            $y = ceil(($height - $width) / 2);
            $height = $width;
        }
```

Any Help would be appreciated, Thanks in advanced,
J

Here is the full function..

```
function create_thumbnail($source,$destination, $thumb_width) {
        $percent = 0.5;
        $size = getimagesize($source);
        $width = $size[0];
        $height = $size[1];
        $x = 0;
        $y = 0;
        if($width> $height) {
            $x = ceil(($width - $height) / 2 );
            $width = $height;
        } elseif($height> $width) {
            $y = ceil(($height - $width) / 2);
            $height = $width;
        }
        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumb_width,$thumb_width)or die('Cannot Initialize new GD image stream');
        $extension = get_image_extension($source);
         if($extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg') 
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source); 
        if($extension=='gif') 
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source); 
        if($extension=='png') 
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);   

        imagecopyresampled($new_image,$image,0,0,$x,$y,$thumb_width,$thumb_width,$width,$height);
        if($extension=='jpg' || $extension=='jpeg') 
           imagejpeg($new_image,$destination); 
        if($extension=='gif') 
            imagegif($new_image,$destination); 
        if($extension=='png') 
            imagepng($new_image,$destination); 
    }
```

the `$thumb_width` is 600 and this returns my image 600*600

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean by having the height adjusted based on the width?  Are you looking for a height/width ratio?

Comment: Since you're adjusting the `$height` variable and changing it's value based on the width anyway, shouldn't you actually be passing it to the function and not excluding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked perfectly when i tested it ....  Except you want to work with fixed size

```
$filename = "a.jpg" ;
$percent = 0.5;
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filename);
$new_width = $width * $percent;
$new_height = $height * $percent;

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

Demo